# Manually fail an input field and display error in span asp-validation-for .Net Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am checking a input value exists in the database using an Ajax call -

```
    <div class="form-group Centre">
        <label asp-for="Input.CentreId"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.CentreId" class="form-control" id="CentreInput" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.CentreId" class="text-danger" id="CentreError"></span>
    </div>
```

I have the following ajax call -

```
 $("#CentreInput").on('change', function (event) {
     var urlVal = $(location).attr('href') + "?handler=CheckCentre"

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: urlVal,
         beforeSend: function (xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                 $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
         },
         data: {
             "CentreId": $("#CentreInput").val()
         },
         async: false,
         success: function (response) {
             debugger;
             var $validator = $("#RegisterForm").validate();
             if (response.message == 'Not Found') {
                 errors = { CentreInput: "Centre does not exist in database" };
                 /* Show errors on the form */
                 $validator.showErrors(errors);
             }
             else if (response.message == 'Success') {
                 $("#CentreNameInput").val() = response.centreName;
             }
             else {
                 alert(JSON.stringify(response));
             }
             
         },
         failure: function (response) {
             debugger;
             alert(JSON.stringify(response));
         },
         error: function (response) {
             debugger;
             alert(JSON.stringify(response));
         }
     });
 });
```

I have tried .Validate as above, didn't work.
Tried adding adding failure classes, see below -

```
$("#CentreInput").addClass("input-validation-error");
$("#CentreError").addClass("field-validation-error");
$("#CentreError").val() = "Centre does not exist in database"
```

didn't work.

Can someone help please?

Thank you

Comment: I used to do something like this (don't remember if I added a custom span for this, but maybe I did and set id to "locationValidation"):        if (data.doesLocationExist) {

            $('#locationValidation').text('');
        }
        else {
            $('#locationValidation').text('This location is new. Confirm location is currently empty.');

        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you need to first determine your ajax version, since of jQuery 1.8, the use of `async: false` with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/).

After jQuery 3.0 version, the new `done` and `fail` methods have been updated to replace the previous `success`, `error`, and other methods.

If you want to customize the error message to be displayed in the span, then you can add the `errorPlacement` option in the initialization of the validate method to customize the display position of the error message. Here is an example you can use as a reference:

```
@model CentreViewModel
    <form id="RegisterForm">
    <div class="form-group Centre">
        <label asp-for="Input.CentreId"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.CentreId" class="form-control" id="CentreInput" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.CentreId" class="text-danger" id="CentreError"></span>
    </div>
    </form>

    @section Scripts {
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            
        $("#CentreInput").on('change', function (event) {
            var urlVal = $(location).attr('href') + "CheckCentre";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlVal,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                data: {
                    "CentreId": $("#CentreInput").val()
                },
              
            })
                .done(function (response) {
                    var $validator = $("#RegisterForm").validate({
                        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                            error.appendTo('#CentreError');
                        }
                    });
                    if (response.message == 'Not Found') {
                        var errors = {};
                        errors[$("#CentreInput").attr("name")] = "Centre does not exist in database";
                        $validator.showErrors(errors);
                    }
                    else if (response.message == 'Success') {
                       
                         $("#CentreNameInput").val(response.centreName);
                         alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("AJAX request failed: " + errorThrown);
                });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("CheckCentre")]
public IActionResult CheckCentre( CentreInputModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.CentreId == 1)
        {
            return Json(new { message = "Success", centreName = "Example Centre" });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { message = "Not Found", centreName = "Not Found Centre" });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(new { message = "Validation Failed", errors = ModelState });
    }
}
```

When the data I pass in can be found
[image]

When the data I pass in does not exist

[image]